# Backup or read settings of a nucleo board stm32

Tags: stm32, lora, nucleo, stm32l152

I was wondering if it is possible to back up or read the settings of a nucleo board stm32. It is set up as a P-NUCLEO-LRWAN1 Nucleo pack. Which uses LoRaWAN to send data to a gateway and it works perfectly. I was now wondering if I could change the configuration (like lora settings, data format, etc).

I already tried using stm32 st-link utility, and Keil IDE. But they only flash or erase the board. I don't know how to read it.

I don't have any background on this so, details would be great. Apologies if I used the wrong words to describe things. Thanks!

Comment: *"I already tried using stm32 st-link utility, and Keil IDE. But they only flash or erase the board. I don't know how to read it."* ST LINK utility should be able to read the EEPROM or FLASH memory. Check if the **level 1 read out protection** mechanism is not enabled. The read protection Level 1 is activated by writing any value (except for 0xAA and 0xCC used to set Level 0 and Level 2, respectively) into the RDP option byte. When Level 1 is active, programming the protection option byte (RDP) to Level 0 causes the Flash memory and the backup SRAM to be mass-erased.

Comment: Could you please specify:1. What is the board you're using(is it Nucleo-L073RZ with SX1272 shield)? 2.What stack/code do you use, and where did you get it? 3. Did you try to use/compile I-CUBE-LRWAN?

Answer (score -1):

You can read memory by "st-link utility" software (if you have st-link, of course)
Under "icon menu" you have **two text fields: Address and size**. Just set correct address and window below will display necessary memory region.

To save data just Select menu File->Save file...

Answer (score -1):

You need to save it into the FLASH memory. FLASH memory can be erased and programed runtime. Read your micro Reference Manual where the procedure of erasing and writing the FLASH page is described in details.